# Coefficient of variation (COVAR) function

Tags: r, function

I´m trying to create a function to calculate covar as following:

```
covar <- function(x){
    coef<-sd(x)/mean(x)*100
    return(coef)
}
```

Sometimes when I try to run the function as below the following output appears:

```
covar(df$var_leilao) 
[1] NA
```

I believe that this is caused by the fact that I have some missing values, and I would like to put an `na.rm = TRUE` argument in the function to run something like this:

```
covar(df$var_leilao, na.rm = TRUE)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add an argument to your function, then reference its value at the appropriate places in the function body. Here I'm adding an additional argument called "na.rm", which is in turn referenced by `mean` and `sd`.

By specifying `na.rm = TRUE` in the function signature, I'm telling R that TRUE is the default value for this argument. Calling `covar(x)` is the same as calling `covar(x, na.rm = TRUE)`.

```
covar <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
  coef <- sd(x, na.rm = na.rm) / mean(x, na.rm = na.rm) * 100
  return(coef)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by incorporating an na.rm statement in both the sd() and mean() functions:

```
# Create variable
var_leilao <- c(seq(1, 100), NA)

# Co-variance function with na.rm (TRUE by default)
covar <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
  coef <- sd(x, na.rm = na.rm) / mean(x, na.rm = na.rm) * 100
  return(coef)
}

# Without NAs
covar(var_leilao)

# With NAs
covar(var_leilao, na.rm = FALSE)
```